# PDFKit broken when using Noto Sans font

Tags: node-pdfkit

I'm trying to generate a pdf with Node.js using [PDFKit](http://pdfkit.org/). The pdf contains text in multiple languages, including arabic and russian, so I'm trying to use [Noto Sans](https://www.google.com/get/noto/#sans-lgc) from Google, but as soon as I use that font, the layout is totally broken, not showing even latin characters:

```
var doc = new PDFDocument();
doc.registerFont('NotoSans', 'fonts/NotoSans-Regular.ttf');
doc.font('NotoSans');
doc.pipe(res);
doc.fontSize(15);
doc.text('UTF-8 Test');
doc.text('صباح الخیر');
doc.text('japanese');
doc.text('武大郎');
doc.text('RUSSIAN');
doc.text('Привет / здравствуйте');
doc.end();
```

But this is the result. I expected japanese not to work, but nothing gets displayed correctly. This is the output I get:

[image]

Using specific fonts for japanese and arabic works rendering that language, but I need a font that support multiple languages because I'm printing a dynamic table and I don't even know which languages are needed.

Answer (score 2):

You're problem is that NotoSans-Regular.ttf doesn't have all the characters you're looking for. It only has Cyrillic, Greek, Latin characters:

> Afrikaans, Aghem, Akan, Albanian, Asu, Azerbaijani, Bafia, Bambara,
>   Basaa, Basque, Belarusian, Bemba, Bena, Bosnian, Breton, Bulgarian,
>   Catalan, Central Atlas Tamazight, Chiga, Colognian, Cornish, Croatian,
>   Czech, Danish, Duala, Dutch, Embu, English, Esperanto, Estonian, Ewe,
>   Ewondo, Faroese, Filipino, Finnish, French, Friulian, Fulah, Galician,
>   Ganda, German, Greek, Gusii, Hausa, Hawaiian, Hungarian, Icelandic,
>   Igbo, Indonesian, Irish, Italian, Jola-Fonyi, Kabuverdianu, Kabyle,
>   Kalaallisut, Kalenjin, Kamba, Kazakh, Kikuyu, Kinyarwanda, Koyra
>   Chiini, Koyraboro Senni, Kwasio, Kyrgyz, Langi, Latvian, Lingala,
>   Lithuanian, Luba-Katanga, Luo, Luyia, Macedonian, Machame,
>   Makhuwa-Meetto, Makonde, Malagasy, Malay, Maltese, Manx, Masai, Meru,
>   Mongolian, Morisyen, Mundang, Nama, North Ndebele, Northern Sami,
>   Norwegian Bokmål, Norwegian Nynorsk, Nuer, Nyankole, Oromo, Polish,
>   Portuguese, Romanian, Rombo, Rundi, Russian, Rwa, Sakha, Samburu,
>   Sango, Sangu, Sena, Serbian, Shambala, Shona, Slovak, Slovenian, Soga,
>   Somali, Spanish, Swahili, Swedish, Swiss German, Taita, Tajik,
>   Tasawaq, Teso, Tongan, Turkish, Ukrainian, Uzbek, Vietnamese, Vunjo,
>   Walser, Welsh, Yangben, Yoruba, Zarma, Zulu

You need to load Noto-San in all the languages you're using.

Clone the nato into your project directory:

```
git clone git@github.com:googlei18n/noto-fonts.git
```

If you need Korean, Japanese, or Chinese clone these fonts as well:

```
git clone git@github.com:googlei18n/noto-cjk.git
```

Now that you have the fonts you want to use you need to register them

```
// Default
doc.registerFont('NotoSans', 'noto-ckj/hinted/Noto-Regular.ttf');
// Ariabic
doc.registerFont('NotoSansAR', 'noto-ckj/hinted/NotoKufiArabic-Regular.ttf');
// Chines, Korean, Japanese
doc.registerFont('NotoSansCKJ', 'noto-ckj/NotoSansCJK-Regular.ttc');
```

Once you've got the appropriate font's loaded then you can use them like so:

```
doc.font('NotoSans');
doc.text('English');

doc.font('NotoSansAR');
doc.text('العربية'); // Arabic

doc.font('NotoSansCKJ');
doc.text('日本語'); // Japanese
doc.text('武大郎'); // Chinese
doc.text('한국어'); // Korean

doc.font('NotoSans');
doc.text('русский'); // Russian
doc.text('ελληνικά'); // Greek
```

Be careful that you're not loading too many fonts into your PDF since they'll add to the overall size of you document. You may consider using a library like [Franc](https://github.com/wooorm/franc) to figure out which fonts you need before loading them.

Comment: P.S. I noticed that when using the unhinted (instead of hinted) I saw some of the same results you did.

This is from [Googles Style Guide](https://material.google.com/style/typography.html#typography-typeface): "Hints are the instructions embedded in a font on how to modify (distort) a glyph to look better on low-resolution displays. As a tradeoff, a hinted font consumes more space than the unhinted version."

Comment: That makes sense, but I'm still confused because if I remove all the other languages, even the english text doesn't work. Thanks for the Franc link, I'll check it and see if I can use for dynamic language (I don't know what language I'll be printing)

Comment: If you clone the git repo mentioned above you'll notice to subdirectories: "hinted" and "unhinted" make sure you're using the "hinted" version of the font. I had the same problem with the "unhinted".